# Rabbitmq problem with requeue expired messages

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have created two exchanges WORKER and RETRY. And I set DLX to resend expired or rejected messages to original queue, but my messages are disappear in RETRY queue. Problem is that the expired messages do not fall into work.exchange. But with rejected messages working well.
Pls help. Can you give me some explanation and solution.
[image]

this conf of retry.queue
[image]

thid conf of work.queue
[image]

Comment: You need to show your queue and DLQ definitions and their bindings.

Comment: I did same as like [link](https://medium.com/@igkuz/ruby-retry-scheduled-tasks-with-dead-letter-exchange-in-rabbitmq-9e38aa39089b)

Comment: With rejected messages working good, but expired messages are disappear in RETRY queue.

Comment: You might claim you did that, but you need to show exactly what your configuration looks like. I can assure you that the pattern works when properly configured.

Comment: Problem is that the expired messages do not fall into work.exchange. But with rejected messages working well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Problem is that the expired messages do not fall into work.exchange. But with rejected messages working well.

You should have explained that in your original question.

You are not allowed to create an expiry cycle; only reject then expire.

See [the documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html).

> It is possible to form a cycle of message dead-lettering. For instance, this can happen when a queue dead-letters messages to the default exchange without specifiying a dead-letter routing key. Messages in such cycles (i.e. messages that reach the same queue twice) **will be dropped if there was no rejections in the entire cycle.**

Comment: You can achieve what you want with 3 queues and an alwaysRejectConsumer on the third queue. Q1 expire. Q2 expire Q3 reject and dlq to Q1.